# Excel Formula that increments academic grade each year

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am having significant trouble creating a simple formula in Excel. Imagine I have a table of students and their current academic grade. I would like to have a formula that automatically recognizes how much time has passed since the base date the spreadsheet was created, and will increment every student's academic grade by one based on how many years it has been since the base date. I would like it to increment the grade based on how many times it has been June 1st, as that is around the time summer starts and you can consider students to be in the next grade.

Some things I have tried and some parameters I'm setting:

I would like to be able to have the grade start from "not in school", then "Pre-K 3", "Pre-K 4", "Kindergarten", "1st", "2nd", ... "12th", and, finally, "graduated high school".

I have assigned each academic grade an integer value so that the integer value can be incremented. I assigned 1 to "not in school" and 2 to "Pre-K 3" and so on until "graduated high" school is 17.

Essentially I am assigning this base value to each student for the grade they are currently in when the spreadsheet is being created.

When opening this spreadsheet in the future, I want the formula to calculate how long it has been since the creation date, how many times this has meant it has been June 1st, and this number of times is the number of times to increment each academic grade integer for each student which will then be reflected by the string the integer represents.

I am having trouble "incrementing" anything in Excel. Excel does not seem to have this functionality built in. I am trying to avoid using VBA.

For simplicity, let's say:

my range of all grades is called "Grades",

my range of all grade integer values is called "Grade_Values",

my range of students' base grade is called "Beginning_Grade",

and my base date is 01/01/2024.

Answer (score 1):

First, Excel (and all other spreadsheets?) stores dates as a day-count from a 'base date', the decimal portion of the same number specifies how far into that date the related TIME of day is:
Enter a `0` in any cell and change the `Cell formatting` (CTRTL+1) to `Date` to see the base date.

https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060102.html - has all of the date and time related functions listed. *(I don't know if the  same can be found for Excel)*.

The first optional way to try (if it gives good enough result) is simply:
`=INT( (TODAY()-A1) / 365.25 )`
... where 365.25 is the average day count per year, assuming you have a "start date" in A1.
This will give you the number of years that has passed between the dates.
*You may have to tweak it a bit to get what you want for your application.*
*Negative values would be "not in school", 0 and up telling how far into the schooling this person has gone.*

Note also that the `TEXT()` function can provide you with a custom (string) repesentation of a date; it uses the same formatting string as `Cell formatting` - i.e. as show [here](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/01/05020301.html?DbPAR=SHARED#bm_id3153514).

With some thinking you might come up with a more precise formula, (if it really is required).